# Bash, remove lines containing string with grep

Tags: grep, io-redirection

This is currently deleting the whole contents of the file in question:

```
#!/bin/bash
rpc_port="9201";
dir="/etc/apache2/ports.conf"
cat $dir | grep -v "Listen $rpc_port" > $dir
```

The file contents:

```
Listen 9200
Listen 9201
Listen 9202
Listen 9203
Listen 9204
```

Could someone please either fix this or give me a working alternative?

Comment: The pipe from cat to grep is a bit useless here, as you could have done `grep pattern $dir`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot write (=redirect) to the same file you are reading from. Either redirect to a different file, or use sed.

```
sed -i "/$rpc_port/d" $dir
```

Comment: ah, I see :P tyvm for your help, that works great :D